# How to specify color for elements in plotly Gannt chart?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm following the python tutorial here: https://plotly.com/python/gantt/

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-25'),
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-02-26', Finish='2009-03-28'),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')
])

print(df)

    Task       Start      Finish
0  Job A  2009-01-01  2009-02-25
1  Job A  2009-02-26  2009-03-28
2  Job B  2009-03-05  2009-04-15
3  Job C  2009-02-20  2009-05-30
```

The code in the tutorial above gives me the chart:

```
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up
fig.show()
```

[image]

Notice that there are two events for `Job A`.

I would like to alternate the colors for each start and finish. For example First event red, second event blue, third event red, fourth event blue etc.

I have tried the `color_discrete_sequence` and `color_discrete_map` arguments, but the colors do not alternate.

What I have tried:

```
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task",color_discrete_sequence=["red", "blue"])
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") 
fig.show()
```

and

```
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task",color_discrete_map={"Start": "red","Finish":'blue'})
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") 
fig.show()
```

Any ideas on how to alternate the colors?

AN example of what I want it to look like for Job A:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a column that describes the desired color and map the description to the actual color. Without the mapping `plotly` will assign it's default colors.

import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-25', Color='cyan'),
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-02-26', Finish='2009-03-28', Color='red'),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15', Color='grey'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30', Color='orange')
])
cm = {x:x for x in df.Color.unique()}
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Color", color_discrete_map=cm)
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for the small test dataframe above. But is there a more automated way? I have a few thousand columns in my actual dataframe. with many many Tasks and start and end dates.

Comment: If your question is about color, then you do not have to specify color explicitly. For example you can use column "Worker" with values {"Alice", "Bob, "Carol"}, and the gantt would be  colored accordingly. If it is about how to interleave values inside a group: use `groupby`, create a column  with counter and take a remainder.of division of a counter

Comment: I upvoted but note that the colors specified in column 'Colors' and not used. You happen to have picked colors that plotly would have defaulted to, so it appears to work. But try using 'gray' and 'orange' instead and you'll see it still plots the bars in blue and red.

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention. I have updated the answer.